# If I lose a Trezor then how does the replacement get access to the same wallet?

Tags: wallet, address, hardware-wallet, trezor

I am pretty confused.  What I understand is that when I buy a Trezor then it gives me some words that I need to copy down.  When the Trezor starts up does it then automatically create some Bitcoin addresses and keys?

If I lose my Trezor, then how does a replacement know about my previously created Bitcoin addresses and keys?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10670/5406

Answer (score 6):

Trezor implements BIP32/BIP39 (hierarchical deterministic wallet and mnemonic encoded seeds, respectively).

The mnemonic (12 words) is just a way of encoding a hex seed like `6c5f9d00018f2a2030afcc6f3057e5a4dea6dfb905dd4b0197a9a047bcfe0501662332a3caa846b1223ff3d20cfb295e7f94fe51c94472e3f8429c97754132e9` (whose mnemonic would be `business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh`). The hex seed is then used for a master private key and a master public key pair (in this example, `xprv9s21ZrQH143K29DbrSg2YgC2iyW3Gx3FhNExbxEacDWJCmz9xmsxKjon93FSC85Bv4AkszKLK1d3FA6PKS1Wb6xYotbDppezTMQaazbPL6h` and `xpub661MyMwAqRbcEdJ4xUD2up8mH1LXgQm74bAZQLeCAZ3H5aKJWKCCsY8FzL33Ay3XxoX7xWyq4pejzuSQEQw2hA2CvWvKBgMGTJLgZXRzdbf`, respectively).

So if we look at [this bip39 tool](https://dcpos.github.io/bip39/), the mnemonic *business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh* has a list of addresses which will be used by the Trezor, in order (in this example, the first listed address begins with *18SKy...*).

All of this is just demonstrating how it works (**do not** enter your mnemonic into a website as this example shows!), or as **TL;DR**: *the mnemonic is all you need to recover the keys for Trezor addresses*

Answer (score 4):

BIP 32/39 allows key portability across different wallet implementations. To complement the "Wizard of Ozzie" answer above, a different method (C++ based, not JavaScript based code) is provided below to reconstruct the results above using the bitcoin-explorer (bx) command line interface that should be executed offline with "real" mnemonics and keys.

*Without having high Evaluation Assurance Level (EAL) pedigree ratings ranging from 1 to 7 that also address supply chain risks, one should not put much trust in HD key generators without cross correlating results between different genetically independent key generator implementations.*

Results below were created without a BIP 39 passphrase to reconstruct results shown above. Results below also provide reconstruction details for m/44'/0'/0'/0 (BIP 44 extended private branch key) and M/44'/0'/0'/0 (BIP 44 extended public branch key) that can be used to synthesize over 4 billion private/public key pairs and Bitcoin addresses from a wallet's BIP 39 backup mnemonic words. Only the first 3 private keys and associated public addresses are computed below to establish patterns used to compute 4 billion private/public key pairs and Bitcoin addresses from a wallet's BIP 39 backup mnemonic words.

## 1) Reconstituting master seed using BIP 39:

```
% bx mnemonic-to-seed business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh
```

6c5f9d00018f2a2030afcc6f3057e5a4dea6dfb905dd4b0197a9a047bcfe0501662332a3caa846b1223ff3d20cfb295e7f94fe51c94472e3f8429c97754132e9

## 2) Reconstituting extended private keys:

```
% bx mnemonic-to-seed business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh | bx hd-new -v 76066276
```

xprv9s21ZrQH143K29DbrSg2YgC2iyW3Gx3FhNExbxEacDWJCmz9xmsxKjon93FSC85Bv4AkszKLK1d3FA6PKS1Wb6xYotbDppezTMQaazbPL6h

*Note that [76066276](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L109) is a base10 four byte version prefix of 0x0488ADE4 (base16) that cause the extended BIP 32 private keys to start with "xprv".*

### [JavaScript BIP 44 tab results](https://dcpos.github.io/bip39/) can be verified by the following:

```
% bx mnemonic-to-seed business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0
```

xprvA1hRqX7kSHXAfsq8pNTYtwvgZXDRuUT6MtZ7WHgC8WTquy3LnzZFHRsZfH7shWEqjUPDBgFhXj4o53QPoapPVZUUic944UFbtofrAvzCvmt

#### A) BIP 44 WIF private key m/44'/0'/0'/0/0:

```
% echo 'xprvA1hRqX7kSHXAfsq8pNTYtwvgZXDRuUT6MtZ7WHgC8WTquy3LnzZFHRsZfH7shWEqjUPDBgFhXj4o53QPoapPVZUUic944UFbtofrAvzCvmt' | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-wif -v 128
```

L5TPeiMKRnMbvQF6z1EYa3gmpwP6xSJN21nfAipXnJoD2CVEXGBH

#### B) BIP 44 WIF private key m/44'/0'/0'/0/1:

```
% echo 'xprvA1hRqX7kSHXAfsq8pNTYtwvgZXDRuUT6MtZ7WHgC8WTquy3LnzZFHRsZfH7shWEqjUPDBgFhXj4o53QPoapPVZUUic944UFbtofrAvzCvmt' | bx hd-private -i 1 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-wif -v 128
```

Kx3GxX5o8KynsJAs9jWKYyqKnPmAjVApBr1TNuuXdFkknG8nvJHr

#### C) BIP 44 WIF private key m/44'/0'/0'/0/2:

```
% echo 'xprvA1hRqX7kSHXAfsq8pNTYtwvgZXDRuUT6MtZ7WHgC8WTquy3LnzZFHRsZfH7shWEqjUPDBgFhXj4o53QPoapPVZUUic944UFbtofrAvzCvmt' | bx hd-private -i 2 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-wif -v 128
```

L16rfuc8mPts63KcovJH57rwqGfQP48q6hV3mHgbi9fbiX9gAEPp

## 3) Reconstituting extended public keys:

```
% bx mnemonic-to-seed business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh | bx hd-new -v 76067358
```

xpub661MyMwAqRbcEdJ4xUD2up8mH1LXgQm74bAZQLeCAZ3H5aKJWKCCsY8FzEPiHJDnKncknSSFymNVrbeBD6W4LxYiKtubg9U3PDHpM7DEZx7

*Note that [76067358](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L108) is a base10 four byte version prefix of 0x0488B21E (base16) that causes the extended BIP 32 public keys to start with "xpub".*

### [JavaScript BIP 44 tab results](https://dcpos.github.io/bip39/) can be verified by the following:

```
% bx mnemonic-to-seed business weird season glimpse pole robot surprise next term toddler doctor fresh | bx hd-new -v 76066276 | bx hd-private -d -i 44 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-private -d -i 0 | bx hd-public -i 0
```

xpub6EgnF2eeGf5TtMubvPzZG5sR7Z3vJwAwj7UiJg5ogqzpnmNVLXsVqEC3Wa4g8djxA9JcPFB9rSW9qvjYYCNbhJHkh7Pnm2uWUh5ZJ3pYNBj

#### A) Address for BIP 44 public key M/44'/0'/0'/0/0:

```
% echo 'xpub6EgnF2eeGf5TtMubvPzZG5sR7Z3vJwAwj7UiJg5ogqzpnmNVLXsVqEC3Wa4g8djxA9JcPFB9rSW9qvjYYCNbhJHkh7Pnm2uWUh5ZJ3pYNBj' | bx hd-public -i 0 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-address -v 0
```

18SKy9bqE57Mif4p1iGbGqPP2vgV8YXFw8

#### B) Address for BIP 44 public key M/44'/0'/0'/0/1:

```
% echo 'xpub6EgnF2eeGf5TtMubvPzZG5sR7Z3vJwAwj7UiJg5ogqzpnmNVLXsVqEC3Wa4g8djxA9JcPFB9rSW9qvjYYCNbhJHkh7Pnm2uWUh5ZJ3pYNBj' | bx hd-public -i 1 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-address -v 0
```

13EGK6DifQ6jsx5habBz4SoNYitPaqYUTL

#### C) Address for BIP 44 public key M/44'/0'/0'/0/2:

```
% echo 'xpub6EgnF2eeGf5TtMubvPzZG5sR7Z3vJwAwj7UiJg5ogqzpnmNVLXsVqEC3Wa4g8djxA9JcPFB9rSW9qvjYYCNbhJHkh7Pnm2uWUh5ZJ3pYNBj' | bx hd-public -i 2 | bx hd-to-ec | bx ec-to-address -v 0
```

1JMeSGf1AB6vsRQxRJsVFBtRmqWdbNcn5D

*It is worth noting bx unifies key HD key/address generation across 100+ altcoins, see [BIP 44 related Table](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table).*

Answer (score 0):

The words you write down are used by Trezor to generate the bitcoin keys and addresses. If you have the words, you can re-generate the keys in another Trezor or compatible wallet (by telling it to restore an existing wallet and entering the words, instead of generating a new one). Conversely, if somebody else has your words, they can also access your bitcoins, so they need to be kept securely offline.